# How to switch from Release mode to Debug mode

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have recently built a release version to test on the Android Play Store. The problem is I can't get it back to Debug mode. When I try to launch in Debug mode this is the message I get on the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM P585 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'..
```

This is what my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.my_app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //enter the latest version
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

However, the `local.properties` tells me that Flutter is still in release mode:

```
sdk.dir=C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

How can I switch from release mode back to debug mode?

Comment: In android studio, there is a 'build variants' tab on the vertical side pane, you can change the current config being built, there.

Comment: @mahee96 When I select it, it says "Nothing to Show".

Comment: see this, buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
This should contain config for debug too

Comment: try using flutter clean command in the directory.

Comment: @mahee96 I have tried that in my code above for `build.gradle`. But it does not work.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Tried that as well and it does not solve the issue. What does work is the command `flutter run --debug`, but there is no hot reload function. I am just doing a fresh install of Android Studio and Flutter now :(

Comment: Can you change local.properties and change buildMode=debug i.e flutter.buildMode=debug

Comment: @KrishBhanushali Tried that. But when I hit Debug that property gets overriden to `buildMode=release`

Comment: okay, I cant comment code so am writing it as answer.

Comment: @meeth23 your buildtypes doesn't contain a configuration for debug, refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In android studio, there is a **'build variants'** tab on the *vertical side pane*, you can change the current config being built, there.

Ensure that the build.gradle contains the build configs first. Else add new configuration by refererring gradle docs or write them by your self, if you know, or pull from a project which contains **'debug'** *build config*.

refer to the attached image.[image]

Comment: I reinstalled yesterday and everything works fine now. I will try your recommendations out soon and see if it works for me.